# mapping between upcall from a kernel vport and the userspace upcall threads

Tags: netlink, openvswitch

For the case that ovs uses kernel datapath, if there are 2 userspace upcall threads and 4 kernel vports, it seems (from source code 2.11.90), every vport will create only one netlink sock and binds it to every upcall thread's epoll_handler.

The question is, if there is an upcall request sent from a vport's netlink socket, which upcall thread in userspace will handler this request?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer already.  The ovs create an epoll-handler for all the netlink sockets and all the threads are listening to the epoll-handler. The first thread pending on the epoll-handler will get the cpu to run when an event occurs to the epoll-handler.